# How do i read lines from a file into a hash in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I'm working with a file format that has lines of information that looks like this:

ATOM      1  N   LYS A  56      20.508  14.774  -7.432  1.00 50.83           N

All i want is the first number, and the three numbers following '56' in the example above; so im using regular expressions to get that information. How do i then put that info into a hash?

So far i have:

```
my $pdb_file = $ARGV[0];
open (PDBFILE, "<$pdb_file") or die ("$pdb_file not found");
while (<PDBFILE>) { 
if ($_=~ /^ATOM\s+(\d+)\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)/) {
my $atom = $1;
my $xcor = $2;
my $ycor = $3;
my $zcor = $4;
print "AtomNumber: $atom\t  xyz: $xcor $ycor $zcor\n";
}
}
```

Comment: `$myhash{ $atom } = [ $xcor, $ycor, $zcor ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a regex, I would instead recommend using [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to split it into fields on whitespace. This will be faster and more robust, it doesn't depend on a detailed knowledge of the format of each field (which could change, like if a number has a minus sign which you forgot to take into account). And it's a lot easier to understand.

```
my @fields = split /\s+/, $line;
```

Then you can pick out the fields (for example, the first number is field 2, so `$fields[1]`) and put them into your hash.

```
my %coordinate = (
    atom => $fields[1],
    x    => $fields[6],
    y    => $fields[7],
    z    => $fields[8]
);
```

You're reading a bunch of lines, so you're going to make a bunch of hashes which have to go somewhere.  I'd recommend putting them all in another hash with some sort of unique field as the key.  Possibly the `atom` field.

```
$atoms{$coordinate{atom}} = \%coordinate;
```